# Is it possible to go through registration without a passport and a visa?

Tags: phd, international-students, international, visa

I lost my passport with a F1 Visa today, 1 week before registration at SUNY Buffalo (I am attending as a PhD student), will it prevent me from being registered if I don't have a passport with the stamped visa by the time I arrive (I am already in the U.S)? I can't contact the university staff since it's Saturday and I am freaking out with no clue on how to proceed.

Comment: The US has gotten a bit weird lately, but I'll guess that if you talk to the university directly they will try very hard to manage the issue. Don't panic until you have a better idea of your options and the university response. Contact the university first, but you will probably need to also contact the police. Perhaps the university police would be better than other possibilities.

Comment: Also, contact your consulate to get started on the process of getting a replacement passport.  The sooner the better.

Comment: Get a replacement passport and contact the university's international office ASAP. IANAL, but I think you can stay in the US without a visa and only need to get a new one to re-enter, so you might be OK. Do you have a scanned copy of your visa?